# Parsing a binary message in C++. Any lib with examples?

Tags: c++, parsing, bit-manipulation

I am looking for any library of example parsing a binary msg in C++. Most people asks for reading a binary file, or data received in a socket, but I just have a set of binary messages I need to decode. [Somebody mentioned boost::spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214863/name-me-a-binary-parser-a-parser-for-binary-data), but I haven't been able to find a suitable example for my needs.

As an example:
9A690C12E077033811FFDFFEF07F042C1CE0B704381E00B1FEFFF78004A92440

where first 8 bits are a preamble, next 6 bits the msg ID (an integer from 0 to 63), next 212 bits are data, and final 24 bits are a CRC24.

So in this case, msg 26, I have to get this data from the 212 data bits:

- 4 bits integer value
- 4 bits integer value
- A 9 bit float value from 0 to 63.875, where LSB is 0.125
- 4 bits integer value

**EDIT: I need to operate at bit level, so a memcpy is not a good solution, since it copies a number of bytes. To get first 4-bit integer value I should get 2 bits from a byte, and another 2 bits from the next byte, shift each pair and compose. What I am asking for is a more elegant way of extracting the values, because I have about 20 different messages and wanted to reach a common solution to parse them at bit level.**

And so on.

Do you know os any library which can easily achieve this?

I also found [other Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749325/parsing-binary-message-stream-in-c-c) where static_cast is being used. I googled about it, and for each person recommending this approach, there is another one warning about endians. Since I already have my message, I don't know if such a warning applies to me, or is just for socket communications.

EDIT: boost:dynamic_bitset looks promising. Any help using it?

Comment: You have 212 bits but you said that you need only 21 (4+4+9+4) bits. What meaning of other 191 bits?

Comment: you can have a look at: https://github.com/iso8859-1/BufferHandler. It's not complete yet but it should do what you want.

Comment: @DenisErmolin I said "And so on". If somebody helps me parsing those first values, I can parse the other 191 on my own. Anyway, if you want to know, basically 9 bit float and last 4 bit integer are repeated 14 more times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't find a generic library to parse your data, use bitfields to get the data and memcpy() it into an variable of the `struct`. See the link [Bitfields](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html). This will be more streamlined towards your application.

Don't forget to pack the structure.

Example:

```
#pragma pack

include "order32.h"
struct yourfields{
#if O32_HOST_ORDER == O32_BIG_ENDIAN
   unsigned int preamble:8;
   unsigned int msgid:6;
   unsigned data:212;
   unsigned crc:24;
#else
   unsigned crc:24;
   unsigned data:212;
   unsigned int msgid:6;
   unsigned int preamble:8;
#endif
}/*__attribute__((packed)) for gcc*/;
```

You can do a little compile time check to assert if your machine uses LITTLE ENDIAN or BIG ENDIAN format. After that define it into a PREPROCESSOR SYMBOL::

```
//order32.h

#ifndef ORDER32_H
#define ORDER32_H

#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if CHAR_BIT != 8
#error "unsupported char size"
#endif

enum
{
    O32_LITTLE_ENDIAN = 0x03020100ul,
    O32_BIG_ENDIAN = 0x00010203ul,
    O32_PDP_ENDIAN = 0x01000302ul
};

static const union { unsigned char bytes[4]; uint32_t value; } o32_host_order =
    { { 0, 1, 2, 3 } };

#define O32_HOST_ORDER (o32_host_order.value)

#endif
```

Thanks to code by Christoph @ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine)

Example program for using bitfields and their outputs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory.h>
using namespace std;

struct bitfields{
  unsigned opcode:5;
  unsigned info:3;
}__attribute__((packed));

struct bitfields opcodes;

/* info: 3bits; opcode: 5bits;*/
/* 001 10001  => 0x31*/
/* 010 10010  => 0x52*/

void set_data(unsigned char data)
{
  memcpy(&opcodes,&data,sizeof(data));
}

void print_data()
{
  cout << opcodes.opcode << ' ' << opcodes.info << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  set_data(0x31);
  print_data(); //must print 17 1 on my little-endian machine
  set_data(0x52); 
  print_data(); //must print 18 2
  cout << sizeof(opcodes); //must print 1
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RomanRdgz structures are aligned at word boundaries by default(which is 4 or 8 bytes). To avoid compilers to pad values(and therefore destroy the structure) we use #pragma pack(compiler dependent) (for it to work on gcc, you need to remove pragma pack and use __attribute__((packed))

Comment: I believe this approach breaks as soon as you try to compile your code on a platform with a different byte-order.

Comment: @PrototypeStark sorry but I don't understand the endian issue. When I was at college, I thought all the big/little endian stuff were about socket transmissions, so, If I already have a binary msg stored into a char buffer, I would think data is correctly ordered without having to check if system is big or little endian. Have I been wrong about that all this time, or just making this assumption because most architectures use little endian?

Comment: @RomanRdgz pretty much all archs these days are little endian. But never assume. simple test to determine endianness in C/C++:
int isLittleEndian(){ char ch = (char)(0xFFEE); if(ch == 0xEE)return 1; else return 0; }

Comment: @PrototypeStark so Endian is about how data is stored at memory, and not how it is transmited from a system to another one? Anyway, how can I parse my example message to fill this struct?

Comment: @RomanRdgz if I am right, your data is in an `unsigned char`(or `byte`) buffer. simply use `memcpy()` function to copy data from `byteBuffer` to an object of type `yourfields`.

Comment: @PrototypeStark but if I use memcpy, I have to tell how many bytes to copy. And I need to work al bit level. Look at the question: 8 bits preamble, then 6 for msg type, and then 2 integer values of 4 bits each. So, for msg I need to get one byte and shift 2 places right. But for the first 4bit value I need to get 2 bits from second byte and 2 from the third. Shift each pair and then compose both together. When I published this question I was trying to avoid this, to reach an elegant solution, and now I am doing the same I would have tried from the beginning. Any other way of doing it?

Comment: You're already avoiding the shifting and composing because you're setting the data straight into a buffer of length = `sizeof` of the structure. see the explanation and images explaining bitfields: href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe(v=vs.71).aspx"

Comment: @PrototypeStark Of, so I just have to memcpy from a buffer to a struct, and that's it? (BTW, broken link)

Comment: @RomanRdgz see the link I posted again and an example I added to my post to clear some air

Comment: @PrototypeStark one more question: is it possible to use std::copy instead of memcpy when coping onto a struct? I know it can work with memcpy, but lately I'm trying to rely on std as much as possible

Comment: @RomanRdgz I would stick with memcpy() its more direct and faster.

Comment: @RomanRdgz see this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707012/c-memcpy-vs-stdcopy

Comment: @PrototypeStark I don't know what's wrong, but doesn't work. Please take a look: http://ideone.com/t3gEts

Comment: @RomanRdgz you mention that its only 250 bits of data in your question, right?

Comment: @PrototypeStark That's it, 31.25 bytes. In that example I am entering 32 bytes, because the extra load are zeros. Where is the problem?

Comment: @RomanRdgz the problem firstly is you haven't packed the structure like I asked you to :). Without packing it will NOT work

Comment: @PrototypeStark I currently have Visual C++ compiler, and I tried with #pragma pack() without success. That's why I didn't include it

Comment: @RomanRdgz I am having VS2010 too. Let me post you the solution then quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate bits for your own, for example to parse 4 bit integer value do:

```
char[64] byte_data;
size_t readPos = 3; //any byte
int value = 0; 
int bits_to_read = 4;
for (size_t i = 0; i < bits_to_read; ++i) {
    value |= static_cast<unsigned char>(_data[readPos]) & ( 255 >> (7-i) );
}
```

Floats usually sent as string data:

```
std::string temp;
temp.assign(_data+readPos, 9);
flaot value = std::stof(temp);
```

If your data contains custom float format then just extract bits and do your math:

```
char[64] byte_data;
size_t readPos = 3; //any byte
float value = 0; 
int i = 0;
int bits_to_read = 9;
while (bits_to_read) {
    if (i > 8) {
      ++readPos;
      i = 0;
    }
    const int bit = static_cast<unsigned char>(_data[readPos]) & ( 255 >> (7-i) );
    //here your code
    ++i;
    --bits_to_read;
}
```

Comment: 4bit_int << wrong variable name. Variable names cannot start with a number.

Comment: you cannot create integers of < 8 bits(=1byte). Hence bitfields.

Comment: @DenisErmolin why using '_data' instead of just 'data'? Anyway, you are recommending static cast, but how do I get the 9 bit float? Because it is not coming as a string

Comment: Do you how float value was packed into byte?

Comment: @DenisErmolin LSB is 0.125, so if I have 0 0000 0001 it is 0.125. If 0 0000 0010 it is 0.250... if 1 000 0001 it would be (0.125)*2^8 + 0.125 = 32.125. At least that is what I understand when I read that LSB has that value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/bitstream-parsing-in-c/184402014) that describes several solutions to the problem.

It even contains the reference to the `ibstream` class that the author created specifically for this purpose (the link seems dead, though). The only other mention of this class I could find is in the `bit` C++ library [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libbit/) - it might be what you need, though it's not popular and it's under GPL.

Anyway, the `boost::dynamic_bitset` might be the best choice as it's time-tested and community-proven. But I have no personal experience with it.